# How to attach onclick action for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I dont know how to attach onClick action with jquery to all the element from the list of attached files.

That is my html file.

```
<p>Attachements</p>
<div>
   <ul id="attach">
      <li id="KjG344D">liu-kang.jpg<img src="/images/thrash.gif" id="delete_file"></li>
      <li id="3ujRCMB">kitana.jpg<img src="/images/thrash.gif" id="delete_file"></li>
      <li id="m3NSxbf">mk2.jpg<img src="/images/thrash.gif" id="delete_file"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<script src="/modules/delete_file.js"></script>
```

Every single upload adds another 'li' to the list above with new generated 'id' for 'li'

That's how my delete_file.js script looks

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#delete_file').on('click', function()
    {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete attachement ?") == true)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/modules/delete_file.php', 
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'json',
                data: ({fid: this.parentElement.getAttribute("id")}),
                success: function(data){
                    alert("File was deleted");
                }
            });
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

And it works well but only for the first file from the list. When I click the second position from the list, or the third, nothing happens.

I know that we can use function for multiple elements like:

```
$('.class1, .class2, .class3').click(some_function);
```

But the problem is that user attaches files, and I dont know how long the list will be.

How can I use "delete_file" action for all 'li' elements in such situation ?

Comment: Ids have to be unique. This is one of the most basic DOM properties you should know.

Comment: `id` attributes have to be unique. This is why only the first one is working for you. Use a common `class` instead

Comment: You can use `$("#attach img").click()`, and `this` / `$(this)` inside the function to refer to the clicked element.

Comment: You could also use data attributes `data-id="delete_file"` instead of classes i.e: `.delete_file`, as in general style guys leave data attributes alone but may delete or rename classes for styling. Use classes for CSS/UI and use attributes/data attributes, identifiers, etc.. for functional use. - `$('[data-id=delete_file]').click(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your links have id's an id has to be unique on a webpage so use classes instead. give each element a class e.g. `class="delete-file"` and then set your trigger onto the class name.

```
$('.delete-file').on('click', function() {
    //do delete
})
```

Also use `.on` or `.once` for attaching the event instead of `.click`
See its documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

to readd the listener when you add elements on the fly use `.once` instead of `.on` or `.click`. then you do not need to worry about the already set listeners and can just re set the events

Comment: `.click()` is simply a shortcut for  `.on("click")`, And this only handles existing elements, won't work for dynamically added ones.

Comment: when he uses .once instead of click it is possible to readd the trigger when a new element is added ot the list just by setting it again. Edited my answer

Comment: I guess you mean `.one()`? Why would you keep re-adding the event listeners when you can do it properly from the start?

Comment: `to readd the listener when you add elements on the fly...` Using delegate event binding already takes care of that, suggesting manual re-binding events in this scenario is redundant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can add classes to your elements `.delete_file`

```
<li id="KjG344D">liu-kang.jpg<img src="/images/thrash.gif" class="delete_file"></li>
<li id="3ujRCMB">kitana.jpg<img src="/images/thrash.gif" class="delete_file"></li>
<li id="m3NSxbf">mk2.jpg<img src="/images/thrash.gif" class="delete_file"></li>
```

**Use event delegation**

*This is to automatically bind your elements with that `click` event.*

```
$('#attach').on('click', 'li .delete_file', some_function);
```

Comment: Will not work in case user added file in the real time.

Comment: How about `$('#attach').on('click', '.delete_file', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    $("#list").append("<li class='item'>" + $("#item").val() + "</li>");
    reAssign();
});
function reAssign() {
    $(".item:last-of-type").click(function(index) {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="list">

</ul>
<input type='text' id='item'/><br>
<input type='submit' value='Add to List'/>
```

Comment: Thank You. I haven't try it because my form is much more complicated than those few < li's >. There are many more differrent elements in the form and such organization would complicate my script more ;).

Answer (score 0):

THank YoU VerRy mUch for Your answers. I solved the problem. And I have learned something new. Creating it as 'class' and using it in jquery made it WORK ! Thanks